# Django multiple view functions for one page

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm tring to make a page on my website where users can pick recipes of which the products are added to a newly created shoplist.

However, there is a lot going on at the page and quite a lot of areas on the page need to be updated after selecting a recipe.

So far the functionality of the page is:
1. Make a shoplist
2. Display relevant values to the user
3. Show a filtered list of recipes to the user on the basis of submitted values
4. Update the values on the page with values from the chosen recipes

In the future I will need to implement even more functionality and I'm pretty sure that my code will become a mess if I leave it like this.

I'll summarize my goals and current questions with the vies that I have made:

1. A shoplist has to be made when the page is loaded. This shoplist is not visible to the user. Only a few values will be.
2. I want to display the values *'budget'* and *'dagen'*. I have made a context for this which is now the same in both views. This is not good DRY code as I understand. How can I rewrite this in a good way?
3. On the page a list of recipes will be displayed. However, this is also pretty much the same between both views. ALso not DRY code (right?) How can I rewrite this part in a good way?
4. Both functions render the same template. This is also not good DRY code (right?)

My ideas:

I was thinking of solving the problems mentioned under 2 and 3 by making seperate extends that can be updated by themselves. However, I need values that are stored in the shoplist to update those extends correctly.

I think I can make a seperate function for making the shoplist that I can call from another function but I need some of the values that are stored in the shoplist. How do I get to those values if they are in another function?

Here are the two functions:

choose function:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def choose(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    """
    Make a shoplist model instance and populate it with BudgetForm value data
    """
    shoplist = Shoplist()
    shoplist.title = str(make_aware(datetime.now(), timezone=None, is_dst=None))
    shoplist.author = request.user
    shoplist.slug = slugify(str(shoplist.author) + '-' + shoplist.title)
    shoplist.budget = request.POST.get('budget')
    shoplist.dagen = request.POST.get('dagen')
    shoplist.vegetarisch = request.POST.get('vegetarisch')
    shoplist.winkel = request.POST.get('winkel')
    shoplist.save()

    if shoplist.vegetarisch == True:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(vegetarisch=True).all()
    else:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.all()

    budget = shoplist.budget
    dagen = shoplist.dagen
    template = loader.get_template('recipes/choose.html')
    c = {'object_list': recipes, 'budget': budget, 'dagen': dagen}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(c))

else:
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed('GET')
```

add_to_shoplist function:

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def add_to_shoplist(request, slug):

# Get the shoplist that is made in the choose view and add the selected recipe
latest_list = Shoplist.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('id')
current_recipe = Recipe.objects.filter(slug=slug).get()
latest_list.recipes.add(current_recipe.id)

# Add the ingredients of the selected recipe to the shoplist
for ingredient in current_recipe.ingredients.all():
    list_ingredient = ingredient
    latest_list.ingredients.add(list_ingredient.id)

template = loader.get_template('recipes/choose.html')

if Shoplist.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('id').vegetarisch == True:
    recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(vegetarisch=True).all()
else:
    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
budget = latest_list.budget
dagen = latest_list.dagen
total_price =latest_list.total_price
recipe_added = latest_list.recipes.all()
c = {'object_list': recipes, 'budget': budget, 'dagen': dagen, 'total_price': total_price, 'recipes_added_list': recipe_added}
return HttpResponse(template.render(c))
```

Comment: you could just pass the data you need to the new function, even the request itself. If you simply pass the request to another non view  function you can still access the post data etc etc. Though it sounds like you might want to try doing this asynchronous with AJAX so the user don't need his page refreshed.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. I also have looked into AJAX and it looks very good. However, I first want to make sure that the page works as intended before I use AJAX